How to Add a Pre-Chat Banner for Messaging in-App and Web on a Website?
I'm trying to add a pre-chat banner to the Salesforce Messaging window on a website by setting embedded_svc.settings.prechatBackgroundImgURL. However, I'm encountering the following error in the browser console:

esw.min.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isCommunityOrSite')

Here is the code I'm using:
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function initEmbeddedMessaging() {
        try {
            embedded_svc.settings.prechatBackgroundImgURL = 'assets/img/letsTalk.jpg';
            embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.language = 'en_US';

            embeddedservice_bootstrap.init(
                '00DBm000001O3Ub', // Org ID
                'MessaginWebBot',  // Chat Button ID
                'https://xxx--dev3.sandbox.my.site.com/ESWMessaginWebBot1724159131779', // Site URL
                {
                    scrt2URL: 'https://XXXXX--dev3.sandbox.my.salesforce-scrt.com' // Optional SCRT2 URL
                }
            );

            setTimeout(function() {
                launchChat();
            }, 8000);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error loading Embedded Messaging: ', err);
        }
    };

    function launchChat() {
        embeddedservice_bootstrap.utilAPI.launchChat()
            .then(() => {
                embedded_svc.addEventHandler("afterMaximize", function(data) {
                    console.log("afterMaximize event was fired.");
                });
            })
            .catch(() => {
                // Error handling if chat fails to launch
            });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        initEmbeddedMessaging();
    };
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://XXXX--dev3.sandbox.my.site.com/ESWMessaginWebBot1724159131779/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' onload='initEmbeddedMessaging()'></script>

How can I resolve this and successfully display a pre-chat banner for Messaging in-app and web on my website? Any help would be appreciated!
